# c# Convert string to Variable

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in C# converting MS Batch files to WindowsForms.

I have need to read in a list of key=value lines from text files and convert the key to a variable.

***Example text***
MailClass=Std
Selectivity=MailNoErrors
MailForeigns=No
ImbType=FS
Postnet=No

I would like to set these as variables to be passed between methods and forms as needed.

```
string MailClass = "Std";
string Selectivity = "MailNoErrors";
string MailForeign s= "No";
string ImbType = "FS";
string Postnet = "No";
```

I am thinking of loading them into a List[] array.

Where I am getting is how do I make them actual variables?

Comment: Maybe a `Dictionary<string, string>` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what is your end goal, since making it into a variable sounds like a means to achieve something more and we can help you out with that

Comment: The original batch files have calls to various functions based on the info that is read in from the text files and used as temporary environment variable.  Decisions are made in the batch files by these key/value pairs.  
Such as If %Selectivity% = "" ? do this : or that.

So, I need to do the same thing.  
These key/value pairs are created as the output of an Access database (eventual conversion to SQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a `Dictionary` would be more appropriate to the task at hand.

An example would be something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // make this global
var file = File.ReadAllLines(path);
List<string> TempList = new List<string>(file);
TempList.ForEach((line) =>
{
     string[] TempArray = line.Split('=');
     myDictionary.Add(TempArray[0], TempArray[1]);
});
```

After you've done that then you can just access you `key/value` pairs from the `Dictionary`.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look this over and give it a try.

Comment: @lsieting sure thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would take it one step forward and create a class:

```
public class MyVars {
    public string MailClass {get;set;}
    public string Selectivity {get;set;}
    public string MailForeigns {get;set;}
    public string ImbType {get;set;}
    public string Postnet {get;set;}
}
```

And initiailize it from the `Dictionary` in the other answer like this:

```
var myVars = new MyVars {
    MailClass = dict["MailClass"],
    Selectivity = dict["Selectivity"],
    MailForeign = dict["MailForeigns"],
    ImbType = dict["ImbType"],
    Postnet = dict["Postnet"]
}
```

Then, you are dealing with strong type entity that can easily be moved around.

You can then have different types as well, for example you might decide that `Postnet` is a `bool` and maybe another `int` var will come along next week.

```
public class MyVars {
    public string MailClass {get;set;}
    public string Selectivity {get;set;}
    public string MailForeigns {get;set;}
    public string ImbType {get;set;}

    public bool Postnet {get;set;}
    public int SomeNewVar {get;set;}
}

var myVars = new MyVars {
    MailClass = dict["MailClass"],
    Selectivity = dict["Selectivity"],
    MailForeign = dict["MailForeigns"],
    ImbType = dict["ImbType"],

    Postnet = dict["Postnet"]=="YES",
    SomeNewVar = int.Parse(dict["SomeNewVar"])
}
```

Comment: This looks like a really good way to handle what I need.  
I will try this as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you want key-value pair in your text file convert to c# property then I think you must use T4 template.

I use T4 Template for database tables to C# class creator, like as entity framework.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126478.aspx

Comment: I will take a look at this T4 Template information.

Comment: Please show how you do this rather than linking to an external site.